# Retrieve Stata variable notes in R

Tags: r, stata

I have imported a Stata `dta` file into R using **readstata13** package.

The variables have notes which contain full length of questions. I found the `attr()` function with which I can do a few things such as extract variable names (`attr(df, name)`), extract variable labels (`attr(df, "var")`), and label values (`attr(df, "label")`). However, I have not found a way to extract variable notes.

Is there a way to do so?

Below are a few lines of Stata code that produce a `dta` file with two variables and variable notes, which can be imported into R.

```
clear
input int(mpg weight)
34 1800
18 3670
21 4060
15 3720
19 3400
41 2040
25 1990
28 3260
30 1980
12 4720
end
note mpg: Mileage (mpg)
note weight: Weight (lbs.)
save "~/mpg_weight.dta", replace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**:

You can actually do this directly in newer versions of `readstata13()` as follows:

```
df = read.dta13("~/mpg_weight.dta")
notes = attr(df, "expansion.fields")
```

This will generate a list providing variable name, characteristic name and the contents of the Stata characteristic field.

---

Here's a quick workaround using your toy example:

```
clear

input int(mpg weight)
34 1800
18 3670
21 4060
15 3720
19 3400
41 2040
25 1990
28 3260
30 1980
12 4720
end

note mpg: this is the first note
note mpg: and this is the second
note mpg: here's a third
note weight: Weight (lbs.)
save "~/mpg_weight.dta", replace

ds
local varlist `r(varlist)'

foreach var of local varlist {
    generate notes_`var' = ""
    forvalues i = 1 / ``var'[note0]' {
        replace notes_`var' = "``var'[note`i']'" in `i'
    }
}

export delimited notes_* using notes_mpg_weight.dta.csv, replace
```

You can then simply import everything in R as strings and go from there.